# Union ranges in Excel Interop

Tags: vb.net, excel

I want a combined Ranges.
How do I combine two ranges into one?

```
Dim range1 as Excel.Range =   osheetTemperatureData.Range("A7:"A10")
Dim range2 as Excel.Range =   osheetTemperatureData.Range("C7:"C10")

Dim range3 as Excel.Range = range1 + range2 '????
```

Answer (score 3):

See this Microsoft KB article: [15: How to Select the Union of Two or More Specified Ranges](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B291308&x=10&y=9)

You need to use the `Excel.Application` object and then do something like:

```
Dim range3 as Excel.Range = xlApp.Union(range1, range2)
```